# Adding +1 in a auto increment value in SQL using vb

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I want to generate an id in my vb program it will get the latest auto incremented number and will add one but my code don't work am I missing some thing or am I doing it wrong? please help me! THANKS!

Here is the code:

```
OpenServer()
    Dim num As Integer
    Dim num1 = num + 1
    Newdataset("SELECT MAX(IDnum) AS IDnum FROM addnewemployee WHERE IDnum = '" & num & "' ")
    txtEmpNumber.Text = "" & num1 & "." & dtpdatehired.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & ""
```

Comment: What database platform??

Comment: its Mysql database platform

Comment: You seem to be incrementing `num1` **before** you have retrieved `num`. This will not work.

Comment: so what should you advice me to do? the IDnum is already in auto increment i just want to gets IDnum value so i can add one to is... is it possible?

Comment: why do you have to add 1 it's already auto increment?

Comment: Its a very very very bad idea to roll your own ID generator (and also to save dates as strings).

Comment: because im generating a new ID with the date that the employee was hired

Comment: So what do you advice me to do guys? Please help me thanks

Comment: What is `Newdataset`, it is not a standard .net function that I'm aware of? Where is the actual Dataset varialble?

Comment: I would advise you to a) always use SQL parameters b) never use global connection or DbCommand object c) Save the record with a standard AUTO increment ID d) create the composite EmployeeNum using that and the date after it is saved...perhaps with an SP (no idea what db this is)

Answer (score 0):

Your method has several flaws.

First, your SQL statement should be:

```
SELECT MAX(IDnum) AS IDnum FROM addnewemployee
```

This will get the highest `IDnum` from the `addnewemployee` table. The problem with this is that if a higher record has been created and deleted. Lets say that you get a return value of *55*. It is possible a record with an id of *56* has been created and deleted.

The query you really want to use is

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE `Name` = 'addnewemployee'
```

Where will get a column named `Auto_increment`. Get that value from the dataset, then increment it.

But **it is a bad idea** to do this.

If you have multiple, dependant insert, you shouild either [retrieve the id at the time of insert](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) and store that in a variable. Or better still do everything in one statement or stored procedure.